# How can I solve the problem with the build runner: "This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled."?

Tags: flutter, dart

At some point, my build runner stopped working. When i try to run:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

I get this message:

```
[INFO] Running build
[WARNING] hive_generator:hive_generator on test/widget_test.dart:
Your current `analyzer` version may not fully support your current SDK version.

Please try upgrading to the latest `analyzer` by running `flutter packages upgrade`.

Analyzer language version: 2.10.0
SDK language version: 2.13.0

If you are getting this message and have the latest analyzer please file
an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/new with the title
"No published analyzer available for language version 2.13.0".
Please search the issue tracker first and thumbs up and/or subscribe to
existing issues if present to avoid duplicates.

[INFO] Generating SDK summary...
[SEVERE] hive_generator:hive_generator on test/widget_test.dart:

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\Users\Home\fvm\versions\stable\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:166:25 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\Users\Home\fvm\versions\stable\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:132:29 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
[SEVERE] hive_generator:hive_generator on test/widget_test.dart:
```

And then an endless loop:

```
[INFO] 9.9s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 10.9s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 12.0s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 13.0s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 14.0s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 15.0s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 16.1s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[WARNING] No actions completed for 15.0s, waiting on:
  - hive_generator:hive_generator on lib/bloc/bloc_data.dart
        - hive_generator:hive_generator on lib/bloc/current_user_class.dart
  .. and 11 more
```

How can I solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What's the SDK version specified in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: Did you try running `flutter packages upgrade`?

Comment: @NirmalCode, environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

without null-safety

Answer (score 2):

If `flutter packages upgrade` didn't solve the problem for you, it probably means that one or more packages are holding analyzer version down. You might check with `flutter pub outdated` which packages are holding back your analyzer. The last time I saw this problem I just manually updated all packages and the problem went away.